# Combining sheets with different number of colums and rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, google-spreadsheets

How can I combine two sheets with different number of rows and columns in Excel, Libre Office or Google Sheets? Example:

Sheet 1:

| Name | Age | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 35 | 197 158 348 |
| Dave | 38 | 394 953 429 |

Sheet 2:

| Name | Email | Birthday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | mike@gmail.com | 2/5/88 |
| Dave | dave@gmail.com | 3/7/85 |
| John | john@gmail.com | 4/6/94 |

Result:

| Name | Age | Phone | Email | Birthday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 35 | 197 158 348 | mike@gmail.com | 2/5/88 |
| Dave | 38 | 394 953 429 | dave@gmail.com | 3/7/85 |
| John |  |  | john@gmail.com | 4/6/94 |

Comment: Ever heard of `VLookup`? This is exactly what you need.

Comment: You can do this with Power Query. Make them **Tables**. Then join the two tables with a `JoinKind.FullOuter`